# asp .net slideshow conversion from windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't have any knowledge about asp .net, what I want to do is to convert windows form application that I created in to asp one.The application pretty much is a slider that takes pictures from folder and shows them on screen every 5 seconds or so. I tried this code in asp net:

```
List<string> keliai = new List<string>();
int sk = 0;
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer1.Interval = 5000;
            timmeh();
        }

public void timmeh()
        {
            string path = @".";

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");
            string[] filePathsPng = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png");


            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                keliai.Add(filePaths[i]);
            }


            if (sk < keliai.Count)
            {
                picB.ImageUrl=keliai[sk];
                sk++;
            }
            else
            {
                sk = 0;
            }
        }
```

Instead of `picB.ImageUrl=keliai[sk];` I use `picB.Image = new Bitmap(keliai[sk]);  in forms.`
When i launch the project i get an exception

```
[InvalidOperationException: The control with ID 'Timer1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.]
   System.Web.UI.Timer.get_ScriptManager() +190
   System.Web.UI.Timer.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +22
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883
```

how should I change the code so the program would work on asp .net too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and Drop control `ScriptManager` from toolbox on your page. Any ajax control you use in our page, needs to have `ScriptManager`.

Your form's html might be as:

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        ...
     <!--Here you might have the timer control-->
    </form>
</body>
```

There are many free jQuery plugins you can use for better experience. May be like :
http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

Comment: It fixed the exception, but for some reason doesn't load my photos even though it does in win forms, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: still doesn't show a picture for some reason, but i found why it didn't even tried to load anything. Because my path was wrong. I assumed that "." is the folder my project is in, but apparently it's a C: disk. I'll mark your answer as correct, as it helped with exception. Thank you.

Comment: Good. But still I recommend to use jquery plugins for this type of work. It will be easier and feels good.

Comment: there are reasons im not using them, main one being i know pretty much nothing about jquery and this project will become much more difficult as it goes, so i'd rather do it with language im atleast a bit familiar

Comment: Yes right. You can keep in your todo list. When you get familiar with jQuery, you can do this. Having knowledge of jQuery will enable you to do lots of things so easily and with less code.